# android menu item enable/disable not work before api 11

Tags: android, menu

Pls help me with this code. I want to enable/disable item according to my needs. It works like a charm after API 11 but not works before. Thanks for any help! p.s. I'm using SherlockActionBar.

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(final Menu menu) {
    final MenuInflater inflater = getSupportMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_favorites, menu);
    AbstractMenuActionProvider actionProvider = new FavoriteActionProvider(
            this);
    actionProvider.setListener(this);
    favMenu = menu.findItem(R.id.menu_item_favorite);
    favMenu.setActionProvider(actionProvider);
    setFavMenuVisible(!isLoading);
    // TODO favorite is null!
    favorite = (ToggleButton) favMenu.getActionView().findViewById(
            R.id.favorite);
    return true;
}

@SuppressLint("NewApi")
// TODO works only after API 11
private void setFavMenuVisible(boolean visible) {
    if (favMenu != null) {
        favMenu.setVisible(visible);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
            invalidateOptionsMenu();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

instead of

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
            invalidateOptionsMenu();
        }
```

should use

```
supportInvalidateOptionsMenu();
```